# На каком языке программирования написан .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

apache как я понял написан на языке C. Если htaccess элемент apache, то тоже на C?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12064517/5951529

Comment: .htaccess на языке конфигов апача, у которого нет названия. Причем тут язык на которм написан сам апач. Первая сборка C написана на ассемблере, но мы же не говорим что исходные коды программы написанные на C написаны на ассемблере. И язык конфигов как то не принято называть "языком программирования", на нем же нельзя создавать произвольные программы

Comment: Гитхаб обзывает это ApacheConf

Answer (score 8):

Файлы `.htaccess` написаны на языке, не являющимся языком программирования; используется синтаксис конфигурационных файлов сервера Apache, чьи элементы называются *директивами*. Список директив приведён [*на сайте Apache*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html).

См. также [*статью*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess#Format_and_language) Википедии.

Comment: Языком программирования он всё-же является. Это Domain Specific Language. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA

Comment: @Oceinic, но ведь на практике сложилось, что языки, не обладающие полнотой по Тьюрингу, обычно не называют «языками программирования», хоть согласно определениям они и являются таковыми.

Comment: В Википедии, по ссылке выше, называют

Comment: @Oceinic не верьте википедии. Всегда проверяйте. Ваш же пример, но на английском DSL называет не языком программирования, а компьютерным языком — группой, которая включает в себя в том чиле и языки программирования, и разметки, и прочее-прочее.

Comment: @Oceinic, как раз в википедии по ссылке написано:  *но в англоязычном научном сообществе прижился термин «domain-specific», причём именно «domain-specific language», а не «domain-specific programming language»*.

Comment: Запрос авторитетных источников в вики-статье про DSL поставил. Также нагуглил [*следующее*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language#Definitions):

Comment: «The term computer language is sometimes used interchangeably with programming language.[21] However, the usage of both terms varies among authors, including the exact scope of each. One usage describes programming languages as a subset of computer languages.[22] In this vein, languages used in computing that have a different goal than expressing computer programs are generically designated computer languages. For instance, markup languages are sometimes referred to as computer languages to emphasize that they are not meant to be used for programming.[23]»

Comment: Т. е. некоторые авторы ставят знак равенства между терминами «компьютерный язык» и «язык программирования», другие же разграничивают их.

Следует ещё учесть, что Википедия сама по себе — неавторитетный источник, для корректного ответа нужно анализировать издания по компьютерной терминологии.